# problem of undrestanding return of method

Tags: java

I compile and execute this following snippet of code and I print

```
A collection coming up.
60
```

but I don't understand why "A collection coming up". is printed once

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class RQ400_100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : makeCollection())
            sum += i;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    static Collection<Integer> makeCollection() {
        System.out.println("A collection coming up.");
        Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        collection.add(10); 
        collection.add(20); 
        collection.add(30);
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. It's very hard to read all left-justified

Comment: `makeCollection()` is inside the loop condition, it does not execute every time during the loop.  If you want it to print out multiple times you would need to place the print statement inside of the loop, or adjuct the code another way.

Comment: There, I've formatted your posted code for you but ask that you please consider doing this yourself for future questions. It is not easy to read someone else's code, and so there is no sense in making it any harder than it has to be. Good luck.

Comment: How many times do you expect it to be printed? 3?

Answer (score 2):

Basically the code runs like this:

first `main` is called, which calls `makeCollection()`. When `makeCollection()` is called, it prints 'A collection coming up', then creates the collection and returns it. We then go back to main and iterate over the newly created collection and calculate its sum (60). Then main prints '60'.

The result is that `makeCollection` is evaluated once and main is evaluated once, with the end result of printing

```
A collection coming up.
60
```